# Ecto constraint error on different schema

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here but I'm pulling my hair out over this. I've got the following schema's setup:

```
schema "accounts_providers" do
  field :provider, :string, null: false
  field :uid, :string, null: false
  field :auth_token, Persistence.Encrypted.Binary, null: false

  belongs_to :user, MyApp.Accounts.User
  timestamps()
end
```

```
schema "accounts_users" do
  field :name, :string
  field :username, :string
  field :nickname, :string
  field :email, :string
  field :avatar_url, :string

  has_many :providers, Polydoc.Accounts.Provider, on_delete: :delete_all
  timestamps()
end
```

```
schema "repositories_repositories" do
  field :name, :string
  field :description, :string
  field :fork, :boolean
  field :private, :boolean
  field :write_permission, :boolean
  field :uid, :string
  field :owner_name, :string

  belongs_to :provider, Polydoc.Accounts.Provider
end
```

I'm attempting to insert a record into the `accounts_providers` table but running into a constraint error, but the error is referencing a constraint that exists in the `repositories_repositories` table which I don't think I am touching

```
[debug] QUERY ERROR db=32.6ms queue=9.5ms
INSERT INTO "accounts_providers" ("auth_token","provider","uid","user_id","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) ON CONFLICT ("uid","provider") DO UPDATE SET "id" = EXCLUDED."id","provider" = EXCLUDED."provider","uid" = EXCLUDED."uid","auth_token" = EXCLUDED."auth_token","user_id" = EXCLUDED."user_id","inserted_at" = EXCLUDED."inserted_at","updated_at" = EXCLUDED."updated_at" RETURNING "id" [<<1, 10, 65, 69, 83, 46, 71, 67, 77, 46, 86, 49, 217, 158, 158, 208, 9, 91, 16, 111, 110, 135, 12, 82, 201, 8, 126, 181, 141, 227, 56, 145, 148, 2, 217, 50, 202, 36, 4, 85, 228, 160, 42, 249, 38, 24, 135, 59, 235, ...>>, "github", "1657075", 1, ~N[2019-02-03 09:42:39], ~N[2019-02-03 09:42:39]]
[info] Sent 500 in 1980ms
[error] #PID<0.586.0> running PolydocWeb.Endpoint (cowboy_protocol) terminated
Server: app.lvh.me:4000 (http)
Request: GET /auth/github/callback?code=5bf8f2761b6d3892054f
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * repositories_repositories_provider_id_fkey (foreign_key_constraint)

If you would like to stop this constraint violation from raising an
exception and instead add it as an error to your changeset, please
call `foreign_key_constraint/3` on your changeset with the constraint
`:name` as an option.

The changeset defined the following constraints:

    * accounts_providers_user_id_fkey (foreign_key_constraint)
    * accounts_providers_uid_provider_index (unique_constraint)
```

This is triggered when I try and run an upsert query:

```
provider = Provider.oauth_changeset(%Provider{}, attrs)
Repo.insert(provider, on_conflict: :replace_all, conflict_target: [:uid, :provider])
```

Where `provider` is

```
#Ecto.Changeset<
  action: nil,
  changes: %{
    auth_token: "5ab9b61181eb3bc8221310eb4121a861ebb5b0a8",
    provider: "github",
    uid: "1657075",
    user_id: 1
  },
  errors: [],
  data: #Polydoc.Accounts.Provider<>,
  valid?: true
>
```

Any clues why I'm hitting this error even though the constraint is on another table? I know I don't have the `foreign_key_constraint` in my changeset but this to me doesn't explain the error coming from the wrong table

**Edit**

Here's the changeset function for the `Provider` schema

```
def oauth_changeset(%__MODULE__{} = provider, attrs) do
  provider
  |> cast(attrs, [:provider, :uid, :auth_token, :user_id])
  |> validate_required([:provider, :uid, :auth_token])
  |> unique_constraint(:provider_uid, name: :accounts_providers_uid_provider_index)
  |> foreign_key_constraint(:user_id)
end
```

Comment: Could you also post the changeset function(s). What happens if you take the generated SQL and run it manually in the database?

Comment: @MaartenvanVliet I've added the changeset function

Comment: hmm just checked the SQL and it seems like Ecto is trying to set the id of the record on conflict, and there should be a conflict in the db so at a guess, it's trying to update the ID to something different which is then causing the foreign key constraint in the other table to become invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured it out - it's related to the way Ecto handles the `on_conflict` option of the `insert/2` function. If set to `:replace_all` as mine was, it literally replaces everything which would appear to include the primary key which in turn broke my foreign key of the other table by making the existing records' id invalid.

To fix, I've changed the insert statement to include specify which fields to replace instead:

```
Repo.insert(provider,
            on_conflict: { :replace, [:auth_token, :updated_at]},
            conflict_target: [:uid, :provider])
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution is

```
Repo.insert_or_update(provider, 
    on_conflict:[
       set: [
         auth_token: auth_token, 
         updated_at: update_at
       ]
    ], 
    conflict_target: [:uid, :provider])
```